# Is it possible to update subscription message using previous state?

Tags: java, kotlin, axon

Suppose I have this subscription query like this:

```java
queryGateway.subscriptionQuery(
    FetchListOfBookQuery,
    ResponseTypes.multipleInstancesOf(Book::class.java),
    ResponseTypes.multipleInstancesOf(Book::class.java)
)
```

So, it will subscribe to list of the `Book`s in databsae and If I want to add a new book I would have something like this in my projection:

```kotlin
fun on(event: BookAddedEvent){
    var book = repo.save(Book(event.bookId)).block()
    queryUpdateEmitter.emit(
        FetchListOfBookQuery::class.java, 
        { it.bookId ==  book.bookId }, 
        book
    )
}
```

The problem is, since I only got one instance of a new `Book` which has been added, in order to update to the subscription query I need to have previous list of `Book`s as well. Is there a way to get the previous update state of the subscription query and compare changes and finally update it?

Answer (score 1):

The Subscription Query logic provided by Axon Framework allows you to retrieve an initial response and updates. In code, this translates itself to firstly hitting an `@QueryHandler` annotated method and secondly emitting the updates through the `QueryUpdateEmitter`.

*What* is being emitted is completely up to you. So if you decide to send the newly added `Book` in combination with all the previous `Book`s, that is perfectly fine. As you have likely noticed though, the `QueryUpdateEmitter` does not store the updates itself, neither does the `SubscriptionQueryResult` on the query dispatching end.

Thus if you need logic to filter out what has been send with a previous update, you will have to build this yourself. To that end you could take the route of building a dedicated piece of logic, a service maybe, which does the job. Or, you could create your own `QueryUpdateEmitter` which enhances the behaviour to simplify the update being send.

I'd argue the latter would be the cleanest approach, for which I'd recommend wrapping the `SimpleQueryUpdateEmitter`. However, this could be quite some custom code, so I'd first check whether there is a different way around this requirement you are stating:

> ... but in order to update to the subscription query I need to have previous list of the books.

If you do end up on that route through bare necessity, I would be interested to see the outcome, or potentially help out with suggestions on the matter.

That's my two cents, hope this helps you out @Patrick!